# How I do to get the domain of page html?

Tags: java, api, parsing

How I do to get the domain of page html? For exemple, the page is "http://www.google.com.br/advanced_search?hl=pt-BR", I want only the domain "http://www.google.com.br/". Does it exist some api for this? Or have I to do parsing this link?

Thanks!!!

Debora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of - `java.net.URL`:

```
URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
String result = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the java.net.URL class. Somewhere between getProtocol() and getAuthority()/getHost() you'll find your solution.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson My point is the point of non redundancy. And what is your point?

Comment: @Serhiy:  I might have a page open for 15 minutes before I get around to answering.  If someone has already answered in the meantime, it is just either more variety for the OP (if different answers) or more confirmation of the original answer (if the same).  As far as 'redundant' goes, don't you think it was a waste of bandwidth to make a comment that it had already been answered, when that is patently clear from just looking at the times in the page?